# To prove a set is countable, is it enough to show it is a subset of a countable set?

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, rational-numbers

A is the family of all circles in the plane $\Bbb R^2$. They all have rational centers and rational radius. Show that A is countable.

Here is my reasoning:

Given the details, the set $ A = \{(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2:x,y,h,k,r \in\Bbb Q  \}$

Since, we know, $\Bbb Q $ is countable and  $A \subset \Bbb Q $ it implies that $A$ is countable

I think this is too simple and it probably has to do with showing $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q \times\Bbb Q \times\Bbb Q $ is countable

I'm a bit stuck. Any help or references to material I can read to understand this would be great!

Comment: "Countable" unfortunately has two different meanings depending on who's talking: either "_exactly_ the cardinality of the natural numbers" or "_at most_ the cardinality of the natural numbers". If your meaning is the latter, then the answer to your question is yes; otherwise you also need to show separately that the set is infinite.

Comment: I am not sure that $x$ and $y$ need to be rational unless the plane is $\mathbb Q^2$

Answer (score 2):

A set $S$ is countable iff there is some injection $i_S : S \to \mathbb{N}$.

So if $A \subseteq S$ and $S$ is countable, the injection $i_S : S \to \mathbb{N}$ restricts to an injection $i_S|_A : A \to \mathbb{N}$, and hence $A$ is countable.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Is there a textbook or any reference material you'd recommend that could make this concept a bit clearer? If not, it's fine. I just feel like I'm stuck on some basics which my current readings aren't covering. Thanks again